# Searching for a TV series/movie about space colonization

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, space-colonization

I'm attempting to find a TV show or a movie. I want to say it's over 10 years old, but I'm not sure. Here are the fragments I remember:

1. Outer space setting, a medium sized to smaller group of people are sent to resupply/reinforce a forward outpost on a planet or moon.
2. After three to six months, maybe a year, they land (possibly crash) and they find the planet is inhospitable, that there's no sign of their forward Advance Team.
3. They receive no distress signals. Their initial scans showed no inhabitants on the planet, but now there's signs of an advanced dead civilization. I seem to remember a family connection to the second team where the parents are siblings of someone on the first team.
4. I believe the second team also had a sick girl with breathing problems. It could have been a boy, but I believe it was a girl.
5. After some searching they find remnants of the first team's landing in some type of outpost, but it has been abandoned for centuries, millennia even.
6. I want to see the TV series because I seem to remember it coming in chunks and it recapping things. There also seem to be some hostile entity machines, people or aliens that they had to avoid I think.
7. I do remember that later they find out that there was some temporal slip such that they showed up thousands of years late. That's why they can't find the first team. The advanced civilization that was wiped out was the first team.
8. I believe that there was a surface city and a underground city.
9. I know it's not any of the *Terminator* series and I know it's not the TV show *Earth 2*.

Comment: Hi Jason! In what country did you watch this show? And you give us the number of 10 years, would you say that 2011 or 2006 would be closer to the time you saw this in? I can vaguely remember a similar plot, but I need to refine my memories. And, was this program in English? Can you specifically remember the name of a planet or space ship - or any other exact detail that might help? Even specific details about their starship.

Comment: Your description is strongly reminiscent of the Stargate Universe episodes "Common Descent" and "Epilogue".  Link with plot summary: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1720536/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

Answer (score 2):

Your description is strongly reminiscent of the Stargate Universe episodes "Common Descent" and "Epilogue".

Link with plot summary: [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1720536/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

> The Destiny once again comes under attack from the drones they previously encountered leading them to wonder just how the drones and their mother ship manage to find them so soon after virtually every jump. More intriguing to everyone however are the people they find on a planet who claim to be the descendants of the Destiny's crew who founded their civilization nearly 2000 years ago. They are only a small party from their home world but have been unable to return there. Eli surmises that the alternate Destiny that they believed was destroyed by falling into the sun may in fact have been thrown even further back in time, leading them to be the founder of the new civilization. After the Drones again find them and the descendants camp is destroyed, they are all taken aboard the Destiny for the return trip to their home world but they are disappointed with what they find when they arrive.

Answer (score 2):

Your description sounds like the series, ***[Earth 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108758/)*** (1994–1995).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_2_(TV_series)):

> *Earth 2* is an American science fiction television series which aired on NBC from November 6, 1994 to June 4, 1995. The show was canceled after one season of 21 episodes. It follows the journey and settlement of a small expeditionary group called the Eden Project, with the intent to journey to an Earth-like planet called G889 in an attempt to find a cure to an illness called "the syndrome".

It's an older series and has a group of people landing on the new Earth and the advanced team are missing and there is a alien life they didn't expect and one character was a boy who was sickly and I think his parents were part of the first team or something. It's been years, so not sure on any of this, but reading your question did make me think of *Earth 2*. But if you are certain it is not that, it also makes me think of an episode of *Stargate Atlantis*; can't remember the name, but they use the city to get more drones for Atlantis in the end.

**Edit**: After posting this answer and rereading your question, the show *[Terra Nova](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1641349/)* came to mind. It is not that old and they did a time jump to go back to a point in Earth's history where the air was more breathable. I think the little girl had a problem with breathing before being sent, but was also why they were caught, because of trying to hide her or something.

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me a little of "Outcasts" a BBC science fiction series that got cancelled after only one season. Points of similarity are (from the surprisingly sparse wikipedia page):

- "on the fictional planet Carpathia, a habitable planet five years travel from Earth"
- "colony discovers evidence of both an extinct native hominid species and a mysterious alien intelligence"
- broadcast in 2011 so a little later than the "could be 10 years ago" from the question

I also recall:

- some parts set on a ship on the way there
- communication difficulties between the colony and arriving ships
- a health crisis involving a plague of some kind
- a personal health crisis involving a young girl (possibly breathing related)

If it was this then you would likely remember the actors "Liam Cunningham" as the gruff, no-nonsense president of the colony, "Eric Mabius" as the oily,devious politician seeking to reclaim his previous earth level status and "Jamie Bamber" as the head of the exploration team...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outcasts_(TV_series)

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1697793/

Depending on your location, you may be able to see some clips (but not the full show) here: https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p00dsk97

Answer (score -1):

[Terra Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Nova_(TV_series)) possibly?

> Terra Nova is an American science fiction drama television series. It aired on the Fox Network for one season from September 26 to December 19, 2011. The series documents the Shannon family's experiences as they establish themselves as members of a colony, set up 85 million years in the Earth's past, fleeing the dystopian overpopulated and hyperpolluted present of the mid-22nd century.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you [edit] your answer to explain why you think this might be the right movie/show, though, i.e. the specific ways in which it matches the one described in the question? Adding a synopsis from a site like IMDB or Wikipedia (along with a link to whichever page you copied the synopsis from) would be helpful too.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Show don't tell

Answer (score -2):

Could it be the Andromeda TV series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_(TV_series)

Comment: Doesn't fit. Andromeda was set on a ship traveling through space, not about colonization